# JMeter synchronize all threads

Tags: java, jmeter, traffic, traffic-simulation

in Jmeter I have this situation:

- ThreadGroup(N-Tread, RumpUp=X sec)

  - Loop1 (n times)

    - JavaSampler1
  - Syncronize
  - Sleep
  - Loop2 (n times)

    - JavaSampler2

What I want is that once the thread group is started, I want all threads to block (syncronize) after doing Loop1. Once the threads are all synchronized and blocked I would like to start a "sleep" phase for X seconds and then restart them all together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) and [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) combination, example implementation:

[image]

More information: [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)

Comment: Hi Dimitri, in the Synchronization Timer the fields "Number of Simulated User to Group By" and "Timeout in Millisecond", respectively what should I enter? in the "number of simulated .." the number of threads in the thread group? and in the "timeout in millisecond"?

Comment: `Number of Simulated User to Group By`  - if you want to block all threads - it should be equal to number of threads in the thread group. `Timeout in Millisecond` - this is to protect you from infinite waiting in case if i.e. one thread fails and won't be able to join the others, I would put something reasonable, like maximum response time according to your SLA/NFR